# How to align TH Header with TD in TBody

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems trying to embed a table in an existing HTML page with some CSS.

This CSS is hiding the header of the table by default with a style definition like:

```
.tablestuff thead {
     display: none;
}
```

But I want the table to show, so I tried setting the style on the thead element with "display:block" (with javascript).  That makes the header display, but the columns of the header don't line up with the td columns.

I have reduced my HTML to the following (hopefully with minimal typos) and showing the style on the thead element as set by javascript.

```
<div class="tablestuff">
<table border="1">
<thead style="display:block">
<tr>
<th id="th1" style="width: 20px"></th>
<th id="th2" style="width: 20px"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td headers="th1" style="width: 20px"></td>
<td headers="th2" style="width: 20px"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

How can I make both the header show and also align correctly with the td columns?

Comment: You should simply set `[thead].style.display=""` in javascript if you just want to show it. Default `display` value of `thead` is `table-header-group`, not `block`.

Comment: doesn't understand your question? what is the problem?

Comment: here i made a filddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ZbdZe/1/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle.  I didn't know about that.  I reproduced the problem there.

Comment: I'd really like to see the solution using "block" - I know it's not the OP's particular question, but it's mine and a SO search turned up this question... - So, same question: how do I align *th* and *td* when I've got a block in the css. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ceja4qaf/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

CSS includes more display modes than the commonly used `none`, `inline`, `inline-block`, and `block`.  There are [quite a few](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp), in fact.

In this case, it appears what you want to use instead of `display:block;` is `display:table-header-group;`.

Here are some examples of the different styles, as applied to your table:

http://jsfiddle.net/CrYdz/1

Comment: What a sigh of relief when I stumbled upon this CSS snippet.  I never used or cared much for `thead` until today and I've been using `table` elements since 1997.  The platform I'm programming in was setting the default display for the `thead` to `display: block;'. Thank God (and thank you aroth).

Answer (score 12):

The problem is caused by the `display:block` in the style attribute for the thead.

Change it to `display:table-header-group`

Answer (score 5):

When you want to show the thead element use this value: `display: table-header-group;`

Comment: I just tried that, but the effect is the same.  When I set theadelement.style.display = 'table-row' then all header elements become visible, but they aren't displayed over the rows of the tbody.  They are all displayed over the first column of tbody.

Answer (score 5):

To set same width for table header and table body in table:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
```

Answer (score 1):

In case nothing fixes it. move your `<tr>` inside `thead` to `tbody`.

this was the only solution in my case since i had so many complications already.

Comment: this solves my issue. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the content of the THs is wider than the content of the TDs and in reality the width is not 20px as set.

So, because you first load the page without the thead, the table gets the width of the TDs. Then, when you display the THEAD by js, the table width continues being the same but probably the THs have different width.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `th` and `td` should be aligned. If you want to leave it as default, just put `display: unset`:

```
.tablestuff thead {
     display: unset;
}
```

### Plain JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("thead").style.display = "unset";
```

### jQuery:

To make the jQuery's `$(".tablestuff thead").show()` method works, your `css` needs to be defined like this:

```
.tablestuff thead[style*='display: block'] {
    display: unset !important;
}
```

This is because `.show()` will set the `display` to `block` by default. The above `css` will set it back to `unset` whenever it's set to `block`.

Answer (score -1):

show and hide th instead of thead with the css

```
/* to hide */
.tablestuff thead th{
     display: none;
}

/* to show */
.tablestuff thead th{
     display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why they are downvoting this. This resolved my issue with table headers not aligning with their respective columns..