# How can i set width of my td and th in percantage - relative to the table width?

Tags: html, css

I am having the following table with fixed header and scrollable body.The problem here is that i can't find a way to set my two table rows to be 50% width of the table.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

th,
td {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

thead > tr {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>column1</th>
          <th>column2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row4</td>
          <td>row4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

why setting 50% of `th,td` does not work ?

How can i do this automatically - so if i have in future three table cells they will expand the table width and will have equal width at the end ?

Comment: do you want to make those rows 50% each or together?

Comment: 50% each, but it is not possible now beacuase i have scrollable tboduy

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153224/3729184) answer, you should remove the `display: block` both in `tr` and `tbody` and the columns will align

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th,
td {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

thead>tr {
  position: relative;
}

tbody {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>column1</th>
        <th>column2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row2</td>
        <td>row2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row3</td>
        <td>row3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row4</td>
        <td>row4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but i will lose the scrollable tbody